I am using Active Directory as Security Realm and Role based Authorization for my jenkins
When I run the script to fetch all users on jenkins, it gives me both active and inactive users. But it is also giving me users which aren't on my jenkins manage jenkins->manage roles->assign roles page.
import hudson.model.User
    User.getAll().each { user ->
        println user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty.class).getAddress()
    }

I run this script to fetch total users.


I only want the users list that are present on my UI page Manage Jenkins->Manage and Assign Roles->Assign Roles

Summarizing above, i want only those users who have any roles(s) assigned

Seems from the comment the Role-Strategy Plugin is being used.
One can refer to the javadoc here https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/role-strategy/com/michelin/cio/hudson/plugins/rolestrategy/RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.html#doGetAllRoles(java.lang.String)
Refering to the command as referred in the doc.
curl -X GET localhost:8080/role-strategy/strategy/getAllRoles?type=projectRoles

Should fetch an output as
   {
     "role2": [{"type":"USER","sid":"user1"}, {"type":"USER","sid":"user2"}],
     "role2": [{"type":"GROUP","sid":"group1"}, {"type":"USER","sid":"user2"}]
   }

Once a list of all roles and related users are provided, one can parse the output to get a unique list of all users. Or better list of users against their roles.
